# PHP post.php mystery

Tags: php, sql-server, post

I have a weird unexplainable phenomenon going on.

I downloaded some source code from a website, a basic PHP script. It came with an SQL to reference numbers as part of the script.

I uploaded the file called post.php and SQL file to my server and ran it - but - instead of executing the code in the PHP file, it loads the content of the webpage of the author of the source code. and stays on my server URL.

The code in the file has nothing to do with the author's site, or graphics or links or redirects or anything.

EVEN IF I delete the entire contents of the post.php file, run the empty file and it STILL LOADS CONTENT from the author's website, where I downloaded it from.

Refreshed browser, restarted, reloaded, you name it. How is this physically possible?

-----UPDATE

In addition when I try renaming PHP files on my server, they become permanently broken "oops broken link" error.

Comment: Can you post a link to where you got the code?

Comment: what OS are you running? windows?

Comment: In short: this is impossible. There must be something else going on, and we won't be able to figure it out with the given information.

Comment: Maybe the script created a .htaccess file?  just a thought, we really do need more info.

Comment: These guys don't want to say it yet...but it's possible you got jacked.

Comment: https://github.com/chaosprophet/Ninja-PoST

Comment: It's a Parts of Speech script + dictionary - no virus/malware found in scan of ZIP file.

Comment: Running Windows 7. The Htaccess file is last modified a year ago.

Comment: my server is going nuts - some kind of hijacking seems to have taken place. things are disappearing - This looks like a non PHP problem -

Comment: not the fault of the downloaded content either - CLOSED

Comment: Sounds like a server issue for sure...

Comment: Graham, check your DNS settings. I bet your router or your windows DNS settings have been modified and everytime you FTP a file or submit a file it's being edited before you view it/edit it/save it. Change the DNS to google dns - http://code.google.com/speed/public-dns/

Comment: voting to close, not enough info, description is wacky, most likely very specific to something OP has done.

Comment: I take the CLOSED comment to mean that you have solved the issue, or at least you know what's ca? If this is true let us know how.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful if you could post some more specific details about what the script was, etc. But, here is my guess. Firstly, make sure that your web server is not doing any caching. If the problem persists, try getting rid of the post.php file itself. Then, I would check to see if the PHP script has created any HTML/PHP files on its own. If all else fails, try going into the code that you downloaded and see what its doing.